# Why doesn't the combined area of the two small squares equal the bigger square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, I was trying to solve this problem from a textbook. The Problem is: "A piece of wire 60 inches long is cut into two pieces and then each piece is bent into the shape of a square. If the sum of the areas of the two squares is 117 square inches, find the length of each piece of wire."

And this is the solution.

"A piece of wire 60 inches is cut into two pieces and then each piece was bent into the shape of a square"

$4x + 4y = 60$

$x + y = 15$

$y = (15-x)$:

"the sum of the areas of the two square is 117 square inches"

$x^2 + (15-x)^2 = 117$

$(15-x)(15-x)+x^2=
x^2 + 225 - 15x - 15x + x^2 = 117$

combine like terms

$2x^2 - 30x + 225 - 117 = 0$

$2x^2 - 30x + 108 = 0$

simplify divide by 2

$x^2 - 15x + 54 = 0$.

Factors to
$x = 6$ and
$x = 9$
therefore
4(6) = 24" is one piece of wire
and
4(9)= 36" is the other

But something doesn't make sense here, If we bend the original 60-inch wire into a square. Then it's area would be 400 square inches.

So why do the two smaller squares area equal, 117 square inches and not 400?

Comment: Because $$\left(\frac{a+b}{4}\right)^2>\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{4}\right)^2$$ (because $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $a>0,b>0$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bend the $60$-inch wire into a square, the area should be $\left( \frac{60}4\right)^2=225$

In general, we have

$$\left( p+q\right)^2 \ne p^2+q^2$$

Hence $p=\frac{24}4$ and $q=\frac{36}{4}$

We have $(p+q)^2 = p^2+2pq+2^2$. Hence there should be a difference of $2pq=2\left( \frac{24}{4}\right)\left(\frac{36}{4} \right)=108.$

Geometrically: Don't forget the rectangle region.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful. And sorry for that mistake I don't know why I 
 thought 60/4 was 20.

Answer (score 1):

The area of a square formed by the full piece of wire would be $(60/4)^2=15^2=225$ square inches, not $400$. As for why the total area of two squares isn't $225$ square inches, let's consider what happens when we cut an arbitrary length off the wire, say $x$ inches, where $0<x<60.$ Now we have two lengths of wire--one is $x$ inches, and the other is $60-x$ inches. Bending both into squares gives us one area of $$\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{16}$$ and another of $$\left(\frac{60-x}{4}\right)^2=\frac{(60-x)^2}{16}=\frac{3600-120x+x^2}{16},$$ for a total area of $$\frac{3600-120x+2x^2}{16}=\frac{3600}{16}+\frac{2x^2-120x}{16}=225+\frac{x(x-60)}8.$$ But remember that $0<x<60,$ so $x(x-60)<0,$ and so the total area is less than $225.$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. And gee, I really don't know why I thought 60/4 is 20.